# How to do sub-sorting in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dna-sequence

Many thanks to the SO community for helping me with the previous problems I had encountered. Love the help here!

I have yet another problem now. I have a flat list of DNA sequences that have associated "Construct Number" and "Part Number. As things stand right now, from my previous code, I have it as a csv file which I open up, read in, and import as a list of dictionary objects. Everything is sorted by "Construct Number" already, but I need to then sort by "Part Number". (It's sort of like in Excel, where they say "First sort by  and then sort by **_**."

Does anybody know how to get this done? Thus far, all I have written is this:

```
primers_list = open('primers-list.csv', 'rU')
primers_unsorted = csv.DictReader(primers_list)
for row in primers_unsorted:
    print(row)
```

A subset of the output thus far is just the following, for visualization of the data I'm working with:

```
{' Direction': 'fw primer', ' Construct Number': '1', ' Part Number': '2', 'Primer Sequence': 'AAGCGGCCGCTCGAGTCTAAgctcactcaaaggcggtaatcagataaaaaaaatccttag'}
{' Direction': 're primer', ' Construct Number': '1', ' Part Number': '1', 'Primer Sequence': 'attaccgcctttgagtgagcTTAGACTCGAGCGGCCGCTTTTTGACACCAGACCAACTGG'}
{' Direction': 'fw primer', ' Construct Number': '1', ' Part Number': '1', 'Primer Sequence': 'TTTAATTACTAACTTTATCTATGATAGATCCCGTCGTTTTACAACGTCGTGACTGGGAAA'}
{' Direction': 're primer', ' Construct Number': '1', ' Part Number': '2', 'Primer Sequence': 'AAAACGACGGGATCTATCATAGATAAAGTTAGTAATTAAACTTAAAAGTTGTTTAATGTC'}
{' Direction': 'fw primer', ' Construct Number': '2', ' Part Number': '2', 'Primer Sequence': 'gtaaatccaagttgtaataatactagagTAGCATAACCCCTTGGGGCCTCTAAACGGGTC'}
{' Direction': 're primer', ' Construct Number': '2', ' Part Number': '1', 'Primer Sequence': 'GGGGTTATGCTActctagtattattacaacttggatttaccacctttcttcgccttgatc'}
{' Direction': 'fw primer', ' Construct Number': '2', ' Part Number': '1', 'Primer Sequence': 'TACGACTCACTATAGGGAGAtactagagttaaggaggtaaaaaaaatgggtccggtcgtt'}
{' Direction': 're primer', ' Construct Number': '2', ' Part Number': '2', 'Primer Sequence': 'ttacctccttaactctagtaTCTCCCTATAGTGAGTCGTATTACTCTAGAAGCGGCCGCg'}
{' Direction': 'fw primer', ' Construct Number': '3', ' Part Number': '2', 'Primer Sequence': 'gtaaatccaagttgtaataatactagagTAGCATAACCCCTTGGGGCCTCTAAACGGGTC'}
{' Direction': 're primer', ' Construct Number': '3', ' Part Number': '1', 'Primer Sequence': 'GGGGTTATGCTActctagtattattacaacttggatttaccacctttcttcgccttgatc'}
{' Direction': 'fw primer', ' Construct Number': '3', ' Part Number': '1', 'Primer Sequence': 'TAACTATCACTATAGGGAGAtactagagttaaggaggtaaaaaaaatgggtccggtcgtt'}
{' Direction': 're primer', ' Construct Number': '3', ' Part Number': '2', 'Primer Sequence': 'ttacctccttaactctagtaTCTCCCTATAGTGATAGTTATTACTCTAGAAGCGGCCGCg'}
```

Comment: Why do all your headings start with a space?

Comment: That was an artefact of my code, I fixed it to get rid of all the spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way:

```
import operator
primers_unsorted.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(' Construct Number', ' Part Number'))

for row in primers_unsorted:
    print(row)
```

Comment: +1: I forgot about the fact that the `itemgetter` supports multiple arguments

Comment: I just tried out that out, but the Python shell returns the following error message: `AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute 'sort'`.

Comment: @ericmjl: Whoops, guess I forgot it wasn't actually a list of dicts. Just use `primers_sorted = sorted(primers_unsorted, key=...)` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it block by block you can do something like:

```
a=0
while a<len(primers_list):
    b=a
    current_construct=primers_list['Construct Number']
    while primers_list[b]['Construct Number']==current_construct:
         b=b+1
    primers_list[a:b]=sorted( primers_list[a:b] , key = lambda e: (e[' Construct Number'],e[' Part Number']))
    a=b
```

which might be useful if the list is very long.

Answer (score 1):

My final code is this, and it worked out perfectly:

```
primers_list = open('primers-list.csv', 'rU')
primers_unsorted = csv.DictReader(primers_list)
primers_sorted = sorted(primers_unsorted, key=operator.itemgetter('Construct Number', 'Part Number'))
for row in primers_sorted:
    print(row)
```

The key (pardon the pun) to this was to make use operator.itemgetter(...), which accepts as many arguments as needed. It's passed into the 'key' argument in sorted(...).

Many thanks to [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) for answering my question!