# Can I use Django style order_by() to sort a list of existing model objects instead of QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, sorting

Is there an easy way to reuse Django-style QuerySet ordering to sort a list of model objects.

Something that would correspond to:

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-field', 'parent__field')
```

Only I got a `list(MyModel.objects.all())` as input, so I already got all the objects and just need to sort them in memory by `'-field', 'parent__field'`.

Comment: Can I ask why you have a resolved list to start with? That sounds like the real issue

Comment: @Sayse I decorate the list with extra fields that are not coming from the database and need to reorder it.

Comment: I'd imagine you could possibly apply [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14416773/1324033) then, since at this point you have a resolved query you could use native python methods

Comment: @Sayse yes but before that I wanted to see if there is an existing solution as I am sorting a list of Django models, not just a random list. Otherwise I would need to write my own wrapper to parse things like `-parent__field` (I really want to just reuse queryset order_by() style).

Comment: Why don't you sort using `order_by` before you decorate the list? If it stays a list it should remain in the same order.

Comment: @tutuDajuju Fields are getting modified after they are retrieved from the database

Comment: I see, so you want to reorder because values have changed. Have you had a look at [lifter](https://github.com/EliotBerriot/lifter); seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @tutuDajuju Thanks that does look like exactly what I need, do you want to post it as an answer. it's funny that that project was just created right when I needed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP mentioned in comments, he has modified the values of the fields to be used for ordering, and now has to reorder the list.

While one can write a simple for-loop/comprehension to order by the required attribute, if you prefer the clean interface of Django ORM, you can use a tool such as the recent [`lifter`](https://github.com/EliotBerriot/lifter/) to manipulate a collection of objects/dicts in the same way:

```
import lifter

my_objects = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-field', 'parent__field')

# ... manipulate my_objects ...

ObjModel = lifter.models.Model('MyModel')
manager = ObjModel.load(my_objects)

results = manager.order_by('-field', 'parent__field')
```

Note that ordering by related fields (such as `parent__field`) may not be directly supported (yet?), and you may need to pre-populate that field with the values of the related object.

Comment: (lifter maintainer here) Odering using multiple fields is not supported yet, but using a ForeignKey field should work ;)

Comment: Okay, sorry about the spam, just wanted to tell to @serg ordering using multiple fields has been implemented in lifter 0.2.1, released today! please refer to [the documentation](http://lifter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#order_by) for more details.